# How to ask ruby pry to stop all other threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, pry

I'm trying to debug a multithreaded ruby script, the problem is when I do

```
binding.pry
```

The other threads continue sending output to the console. How do I make them stop at binding.pry and then start up again when I exit? I'm thinking there's a way to do this in .pryrc

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are proposing using the invocation of `binding.pry` to interrogate all child threads and suspend them until you end your pry session. That is not possible for technical and practical reasons. The `Binding` and `Thread` classes don't work that way, and multithreading in Ruby doesn't work that way.

Threads in Ruby can only be suspended by calling `Kernel#sleep` or `Thread.stop`. (and those are functionally equivalent) Crucially, these methods can only be invoked *on the current thread*. [One thread cannot suspend another thread](https://books.google.com/books?id=VZ4bCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=ruby+pause+thread&source=bl&ots=V_AGz5H4N8&sig=n2rmGnQDbrymhAvH8OwbNN0NBoU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio8Zvy35vUAhWHrlQKHVEdCeEQ6AEIZzAJ#v=onepage&q=ruby%20pause%20thread&f=false). (`Thread.stop` is a class method, not an instance method)

Let's look at what `binding.pry` actually does: objects of class [Binding](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html) encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use. So when you put `binding.pry` into your code, you're telling Ruby to encapsulate the execution context for *the current thread*.

What that means is when you call `binding.pry` in the main thread the Binding object has context for the *current thread* and can tell itself to sleep, but the core Ruby Thread class does not allow it to tell any other threads to sleep.

Even if it did support it, it would be weird and error-prone and the cause of a lot of head-scratching. Imagine that you have code like this:

```
# we are in the main thread
Thread.new do
  # we are in the child thread
  foo = Foo.new(bar.fetch(:baz, {}))
  foo.save
end

# we are in the main thread
binding.pry
```

Because of the way Ruby handles [context-switching](http://www.rubyinside.com/does-the-gil-make-your-ruby-code-thread-safe-6051.html), if `binding.pry` told all child threads to stop then the child thread might stop ANYWHERE in the call stack, including anywhere in the code for `Foo.new` or `.save`. Having those threads pause and resume in the middle of executing code that you did not write will cause you trouble. For example, what happens if an ActiveRecord connection from the pool is checked out and used for a `SELECT` query but the thread got put to sleep before it returned the connection to the pool and before it got a response? Bad stuff. Lots of bad stuff.

It sounds like the real solution for you is to change the verbosity of the child threads. If you are troubleshooting chatty code and your other threads are being noisy while you're trying to work in a single thread, then set the other threads to use, for example, a lower logging level temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

**If binding.pry is yielding inconsistent results, try the following:**

1. If it exists, remove `pry-stack_explorer` from your gemfile and then
   repackage your application. That gem appears to have issues with
   `pry-byebug`.
2. Additionally, not sure if you tried this already but a few server
       restarts couldn't hurt; this has resolved weird issues like this for
       me more often than I'd like to admit.

**However, you may be trying to do something that simply cannot be done with binding.pry:**

One fundamental about `binding.pry` that must be understood is that its scope would include only the current thread, not every thread in a multi-threaded application as you have described.

Hypothetically, if `binding.pry` did affect every thread (again, it does not), this would result in unpredictable behavior especially if some threads are performing data access/retrieval/update operations.

**To accomplish what you want, you may need to take a different approach:**

Although it may be tedious depending on how many threads are in your application, you may need to control/stop each thread individually. Obviously, this can be done with `Thread.stop`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the FAQ](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/FAQ#readline_threads):

> ### Threads don't work, what's wrong?
>
> Some systems (Mac OS X in particular) use Editline instead of GNU Readline. The Ruby Readline library currently has an issue when compiled with the Editline library which makes it block all threads rather than just the one calling Readline.readline() (it blocks while holding the global VM lock, preventing other threads from acquiring it). This can be fixed by installing [GNU Readline on OS X](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X).

So it sounds as if Rubys built with Editline block all threads as you expect and that the developers of Pry consider that to be a bug. I couldn't find any way for using Pry to automatically block all threads from one call to `binding.pry`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646852/7948068) suggests using a Mutex to synchronize your threads before calling `binding.pry`. Obviously, that requires changes to your code and you might not want to synchronize threads just for the sake of debugging. On the other hand, synchronizing threads *does* reduce uncertainty and might make debugging easier without using Pry at all.

As an alternative, you can put breakpoints in each thread:

```
require 'pry'

Thread.new do
  10.times do |i|
    binding.pry
    puts "subthread: #{i}"
  end
end


10.times do |i|
  binding.pry
  puts "main thread: #{i}"
end
```

That'll stop execution for both the main and subthreads at a specific moment. Unfortunately that doesn't help if you want to inspect the the other thread or know exactly where it was when the current thread was stopped. It's also a bit of a pain to comment out all the breakpoints if aren't currently debugging. (But you can disable Pry altogether by setting the DISABLE_PRY environment variable to a non-nil value.)

If you really need to debug a multithread program, you'll probably want to use something like [GDB](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads.html) that provides more support.